# Sumar datos cada 5 grupo de numeros

Tags: javascript

tengo un script que utilizo para contar la cantidad de items ingresados:
Ejemplo si ingreso: aaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaa = 4
Si ingreso 111 5555 2222 1111 = 4

Este es el Script Funcional que utilizo

```
    <input class="input-group-text" id="finalcount" value="0" disabled />
<script>
    $(function() {
        var wordCounts = {};

        $("input[type='text']:not(:disabled)").each(function() {
            var input = '#' + this.id;
            word_count(input);

            $(this).keyup(function() {
                word_count(input);
            })

        });

        function word_count(field) {
            var number = 0;
            var matches = $(field).val().match(/\b/g);
            if (matches) {
                number = matches.length / 2;
            }
            wordCounts[field] = number;
            var contar = 0;
            $.each(wordCounts, function(k, v) {
                contar += v;
            });
            $('#contar').val(contar)
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Quisiera saber como puedo lograr sacar ahora una suma de valores de cada 6 digitos ejemplo si ingreso estos datos:

**111** 2222 333 4444 555 666 **777** 888 999 100 110 120

El sume los valores 111+777 = 888

En ese INPUT Siempre se ingresaran la misma cantidad de grupo de números, no se agregaran letras solo numeros por lo que requiero es que solo haga la suma cada cantidad de grupo de numeros, los numeros ingresados si pueden ser unos de mayor o menor longitud y de hecho pueden poseer 0 al principio ejemplo:

**500** 0512 0512 1900 000 0065 **200** 4444 45 0045 585 4005

allí se debería sumar 500+ 200 = 700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para tu ejemplo, funciona asi:

```
var valor = "111 2222 333 4444 555 666 777 888 999 100 110 120";
var segmentos = valor.split(" ");
var suma = 0;
var i = 0;

segmentos.forEach(function(element) 
{

  //console.log(element);
  //console.log(i);

  if(i == 0 || i %  6 == 0) 
  {
    if(i == 0) 
    {
        suma =  parseInt(element);
    }
    else
    {
        suma += parseInt(element);
        console.log("Suma: ", suma ); //para el ejemplo > "Suma: " 888
    }

  }

  i += 1;


});
```

para el ejemplo con

```
var valor = "111 2222 333 4444 555 666 777 888 999 100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170";
```

sumaria: 111 + 777 + 130 , total = 1018

Comment: Como hago para que esa salida se produzca en tiempo real en `$('#contar').val(contar)`

Comment: ¿querras decir en tiempo de ejecución? con jquery podrías hacerlo utilizando la funcion keypress https://api.jquery.com/keypress/